# To implement Reddit's login feature in Rails, would I need to use RJS and remote_form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, rjs

A feature in Reddit that I like is the ajax login - you enter your username and password on the front page and you never leave the front page even if there is a login error. If your login succeeds, I think it simply does something like a `flash[:message]` onto the front page to say "login successful". If I wanted to do this in Rails, would that be a case of needing to use RJS + `remote_form_for`? Are there any other techniques in Rails that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RJS and `remote_form_for` are the *Rails Way* to do Ajax, but you certainly don't have to use them. [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com) has a [screencast on using RJS and Ajax](http://railscasts.com/episodes/43-ajax-with-rjs) to submit a form.

If you prefer a different javascript library (such as jQuery), you can use its Ajax libraries to perform the correct actions.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Good video.